# Call 2 Ajax calls in one using Jquery Ajax

Tags: java, jquery, ajax

I have a problem in posting the selected values to the database with mismatching values.Here is the scenario where the ajax call maps to the respective Java function. The problem is, I am not getting correct selected values in the DB when the user logs in for the first time. Kindly provide a solution....

**Here is my Jquery Ajax**

```
if(selectedproductIds != '')
        {               
         $.ajax({
                url : "selectedProducts",
                data : "selectedproducts="+selectedproductIds,  
                 type : "POST",
                success : function(data) {
                }
            });
            $.ajax({
                url : "<c:out value= "${saveDemoURL}"/>",
                data : request,
                type : "POST",
                success : function(data) {
                    showNotification({
                        message : "",
                        type : "success",
                        autoClose : true,
                        duration : 5
                    });
                    resetForm();
                    alert("Demo Request Saved Successfully");
                }
            });
```

**The first ajax call maps to this java function**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/selectedProducts")
public @ResponseBody
String getSelectedProducts(
        @RequestParam(value = "selectedproducts") String[] selectedproducts,
        Map<Object, Object> map) {
    List<Product> selectedProd = new ArrayList<Product>();
    for (String prod : selectedproducts) {
        Product product = new Product();
        product.setId(Integer.parseInt(prod));
        selectedProd.add(product);
    }
    if (!Util.isEmpty(selectedProd)) {
        map.put("selectedproducts", selectedProd);
    }
    for (Product product: selectedProd) {
        LOGGER.info("Demo ID:"+ " List of selected products:"+product.getId());
    }
    selectedProdList = selectedProd;
    return "success";
}
```

**The second Ajax call maps to this java function**

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/saveDemo")
public @ResponseBody
Map<Object, Object> saveDemo(@ModelAttribute("demoBean") DemoBean demoBean,
        Model model, Map<Object, Object> map) {
    Map<Object, Object> output = null;
    Demo demo = new Demo();
    try{
        ......
                }
            catch{.....}

    return output;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to this format: `$.ajax().ajax;`:

```
if(selectedproductIds != '')
        {               
         $.ajax({
                url : "selectedProducts",
                data : "selectedproducts="+selectedproductIds,  
                async: false,
                type : "POST",
                success : function(data) {
                }
            }).ajax({
                url : "<c:out value= "${saveDemoURL}"/>",
                data : request,
                async: false,
                type : "POST",
                success : function(data) {
                    showNotification({
                        message : "",
                        type : "success",
                        autoClose : true,
                        duration : 5
                    });
                    resetForm();
                    alert("Demo Request Saved Successfully");
                }
            });
```

Comment: Mude seu código para este formato : Change your code to this format

Comment: Sorry, thought I was at `pt.stackoverflow.com`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% certain I understand what your two functions are doing, but if I'm right and you're trying to perform something which would normally be wrapped in a transaction then you do not want to coordinate that from the front-end at all. A classic example of a transaction is taking money out of one person's account and putting it into another. If that process gets interrupted in the middle due to power failure, laptop reboot, network problems, etc. then the whole thing needs to go back to its original state, otherwise money can just disappear from one account and never go anywhere.

I want to refer you to this question: [jQuery deferred chaining problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7252451/jquery-deferred-chaining-problems)

It's a little different because the author has already figured out that promises may be a key to getting things to happen together. But notice that I answer it twice. The second time is to specifically to explain that transactions should never be coordinated from the front-end. If you have two database operations that must *always complete together* then you must have only one API call which receives all the data needed for both calls and you do them together on the back-end. Technically, even then you should use something like database transactions on the back-end to wrap them so a power failure back there won't leave you with half an operation completed. But failures in the middle of your multi-step processes are 1000% more likely if you try to execute them across the network between a browser and a server. Get that logic into the server where it belongs.